# JSF2 custom component attribute called in ui:repeat always access last value

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, custom-component, uirepeat

I have a very weird problem when using a custom component.

This is my **main** xhtml:

```
<html>
  <ui:repeat value="#{list}" var="item">
    <h:form>
        <custom:component myCode="#{item.code}"
                          intervals="#{myBean.intervals(item.code)}"
                          selectedInterval="#{myBean.selectedInterval[item.code]}"
                          controller="#{myController}/>     
    </h:form>   
  </ui:repeat>
</html>
```

And this is the **component** xhtml:

```
<html>
   <cc:interface componentType="custom.myComponent">
      <cc:attribute name="myCode" required="true"/>
      <cc:attribute name="intervals" required="true"/>
      <cc:attribute name="selectedInterval" required="true"/>
      <cc:attribute name="controller" required="true"/>
   </cc:interface>

   <p:selectOneRadio id="selected-interval"
                     value="#{cc.attrs.selectedInterval}">
      <f:selectItems value="#{cc.attrs.intervals}"
                     var="interval"                  
                     itemLabel="#{interval.name}"
                     itemValue="#{interval}"/>
      <p:ajax event="change"
              process="@this"
              global="false"
              update="@form"/>
   </p:selectOneRadio>

   <k:calendarHeader
        id="calendar-interval"
        dayVarStatus="dayVar"
        groupRows="false">
     <f:facet name="day">
        <h:outputText value="#{dayVar.date}">
           <f:convertDateTime pattern="d"/>
        </h:outputText>
     </f:facet>
     <p:ajax event="change"
             listener="#{cc.attrs.controller.processChanges(cc.attrs.myCode)}"
             update="@this"
             global="false"
             process="@this"/>
   </k:calendarHeader>

</html>
```

`<k:calendarHeader>` is also a custom component of ours, but it has been working for years in several differents scenarios so I don't think the problem lies there. It basically only maps the `change` event:

```
<composite:clientBehavior name="change" event="change" targets="calendarHeader"/>
```

The problem I'm having is that if the `processChanges` function is getting called **before manually selecting** a radio button, it always has the **last** `myCode` value of the ui:repeat.

Let's say my code list has 3 values: 200, 300, 400. The processChanges is always called with 400. BUT if I select one radio button, the form is refreshed, and then the code is correct.

The initialization of the radio button is done correctly, it's just that it seems that the "stored" value of `myCode` before refreshing is incorrect.

I don't understand this behaviour because I have other `<p:ajax>` calls in other areas that work like a charm in with `<ui:repeat>`.

If anyone has any idea about where can the error be, I'll be very thankful, even if I understand that there is a lot of code that is not being displayed here, and thus quite difficult to see an error.

Comment: Just try to use `p:repeat` (if `p:` is from PrimeFaces).

Comment: After some reviewing of our calendar component, there was a widgetVar that had a unique name, and that's why it was not working with ui:repeat (or c:foreach or p:repeat). Thanks!